# remove empty space in product view page

Tags: css, html, product-view

please vist these links

with tier prices :

without tier prices :

in the first link , everything is fine.

but in the second link , we have empty space between "BUY NOW " and  "PRODUCT Tags",

please help me to remove those space

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In The second link the class `.Quick_2` has a set height of `315px` if you set this to be `height:100%;` it will reduce the amount. You should also change `.availability` to be absolute as this is also causing the height to increase.